# How to upload documents/ppt/image in gojs canvas?

Tags: canvas, file-upload, gojs

I need to upload document/ppt/image into a gojs diagram canvas and draw over it. I have a slight idea of how to handle with images but i don't know how to upload ppt/document.

Answer (score 0):

The Kitten Monitor sample, https://gojs.net/latest/samples/kittenMonitor.html, demonstrates what I think you are asking for.

It adds a **Part** holding a **Picture** showing the image in the "Background" Layer:

```
      // the background image, a floor plan
      myDiagram.add(
        $(go.Part,  // this Part is not bound to any model data
          {
            width: 840, height: 570,
            layerName: "Background", position: new go.Point(0, 0),
            selectable: false, pickable: false
          },
          $(go.Picture, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Sample_Floorplan.jpg")
        ));
```

Although that sample has the background image *not* in the model, you can also put the Part holding that image in your model data, if you want.  Typically this will involve defining an extra node template whose purpose is only to create and add the needed Part.  The extra node data object in the model would then refer to the extra node template by name as the value of the `data.category` property.  https://gojs.net/latest/intro/templateMaps.html

Comment: Thanks!!! For image, I can put layerName as Background and i can define image url in the part. If it is document/ppt/pdf should I need to convert it into image and use or Is there any go extension already there like go.Picture that I can use?

Comment: You'll need to convert it to an image if you want to embed it in the Diagram.  I suppose you could try showing the document *behind* the Diagram, but then you need to deal with scrolling and scaling both at the same time to the same amounts.